# change date input format in PHP\HTML

Tags: php, html, shell, date, datetime

I have troubles with date formatting.

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}" name="username2">

$date = $_POST["username2"];
$result = shell_exec("grep -i 'SERVICE ALERT' /home/den/shell/today/logfile-$date-00.log");
```

In `logfile-$date-00.log` variable `$date` is written in **format : mm-dd-yyyy** (for example logfile-03-31-2014-00.log). But in my input, to grep logfile, I need to write date in **format : dd-mm-yyyy**.

How can I change **dd-mm-yyyy** input to **mm-dd-yyyy** file without renaming? Help please :)

Comment: Didn't search helped you? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+change+date+format

Answer (score 1):

you can change your input date format with `date()` try

```
$date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($_POST["username2"])); //mm-dd-yyyy
```

or for `dd-mm-yyyy`

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST["username2"]));
```

and also change your shell_exec() with below code

```
$result = shell_exec("grep -i 'SERVICE ALERT' /home/den/shell/today/logfile-".$date."-00.log");
```

Comment: @Prix check now updated let me know still need change?

Comment: Nope...not working. When i write 31-03-2014 i need to get file 03-31-2014.

Comment: @dend check now updated you have not appending correctly $date

Comment: grep: /home/den/shell/today/logfile-1010-0303-14141414-00.log: No such file or directory
grep: /home/den/shell/today/logfile-0303-1010-14141414-00.log: No such file or directory
grep: /home/den/shell/today/logfile-0303-1010-14141414-00.log: No such file or directory
grep: /home/den/shell/today/logfile-03-Oct-2014-00.log: No such file or directory
grep: /home/den/shell/today/nagios-10-Mar-2014-00.log: No such file or directory
grep: /home/den/shell/today/logfile-10-Mar-2014-00.log: No such file or directory APACHE LOG ERRORS

Comment: It's working! Thanks a lot Rakesh! 'd-m-Y' is working